# How to scrape multiple tables from a page without classes or ids in R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from a [swimming time page](https://www.fhsaa.org/sites/default/files/orig_uploads/sports/swimming-diving/archives/2019-20/state/4A/191115P001.htm), and other pages in the [index](https://www.fhsaa.org/sites/default/files/orig_uploads/sports/swimming-diving/archives/2019-20/state/4A/evtindex.htm) with R, but cannot find any ids or classes to scrape the data with using rvest. The data I am looking to extract is the event, swimmers, and swim times, ideally preliminary and final swim times (from this page https://www.fhsaa.org/sites/default/files/orig_uploads/sports/swimming-diving/archives/2019-20/state/4A/191115P001.htm).

I am quite new to webscraping in r, and am just trying to extract the data, add it to a table, and then automate the process. Any ideas on how to scrape data from this simplistic site?

Answer (score 0):

After some inspecting the data you want is found inside a `<pre>` tag, and for the urls I guess you only want the competition ones.

```
library(stringr)
library(rvest)
# Saving the base_url as the urls are relative
base_url <- "https://www.fhsaa.org/sites/default/files/orig_uploads/sports/swimming-diving/archives/2019-20/state/4A/"
# getting the index page html
indx <- read_html("https://www.fhsaa.org/sites/default/files/orig_uploads/sports/swimming-diving/archives/2019-20/state/4A/evtindex.htm")
# getting the hrefs of the links and selecting only the competition ones and prepending the base_url
urls <- indx %>% html_nodes("a") %>% html_attr("href") %>% str_match("^\\d+[PF]\\d+\\.htm$") %>% na.omit %>% paste0(base_url, .)

# getting all the data into a char vector
urls %>%
 purrr::map_chr(~ read_html(.)%>% 
  html_nodes("pre") %>%
  html_text()) -> info
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Apologies, I was not very clear in my original post, I will edit that. I am trying to extract the event, each swimmer, and the swim times. The swim times are most important

Comment: you could use regular expressions to achieve that. my code gives you all the data that's in the pages and what remains is just some easy `str_extract`s

Comment: @AndrewHicks plus your question is now more obscure as you don't even try to show the code you tried or at least show where the data is located